# Остановить Thread при завершении основного потока скрипта

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Например, у меня есть вот такой код:

```
def loop:
       while True:
             print("text")
             sleep(10)
thread = threading.Thread(target=loop)
```

Как мне сделать так , чтобы после завершения программы останавливался поток?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`daemon`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon) `=True`

```
import threading, time, sys

def loop():
    while True:
        print("text")
        time.sleep(10)

threading.Thread(target=loop, daemon=True).start()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
finished = False

def loop():
    while not finished:
        print("text")
        sleep(10)

thread = threading.Thread(target=loop)
thread.start()

# Программа выполняет какие-то действия

finished = True
```