# Прекращение работы потока

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Всем привет. Такая проблема. Пока выполнятся основной скрипт моей программы, пользователь наблюдает сколько ему осталось ждать во всплывающем окне(ProgressBar). Как только завершается скрипт, закрывается и ProgressBar, а на экран выводится "I am Ready", так вот эта фраза вместо одноразового появления начинает выдаваться снова и снова. Я не знаю насколько мои предположения верны, но мне кажется это связано с тем, что поток работает без остановки. Исходя из этого хотелось бы узнать возможно ли как-то завершить выполнение потока, чтобы окно программы(Kivy) оставалось на экране?

```
class MyApp(App):

    def main(self):
        ....

    def launch_bar(self):
        self.pb = ProgressBar()
        self.popup = Popup(content=self.pb, size_hint=(0.7,0.3))
        self.popup.open()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.go,2.5)


    def go(self,instance):
        self.pb.value += 5
        if self.pb.value == 100:
            self.popup.dismiss()
            self.bottomtext.text += "\n I am Ready"

    def new_thread(self,instance):
        self.threadObj_1 = threading.Thread(target=self.launch_bar)
        self.threadObj_2 = threading.Thread(target=self.main)
        self.threadObj_1.start()
        self.threadObj_2.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Остановить Thread при завершении основного потока скрипта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/682488/%d0%9e%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-thread-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема, насколько я помню, потоки нельзя прибить, но вроде можно расширить класс Thread и уже в своей реализации сделать возможным завершение потока.

Можно вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) глянуть, как это делается.